# Label com Texto Dinamico no Tkinter

Tags: python, arduino, tkinter, label

Pesquisei muito aqui no stack  e no google, fiquei a noite inteira procurando uma simples solução mas nao achei, vi algumas formam de resolver mas nenhum deu certo pra mim ate agora.

Situação: Estou criando um app em Python usando Tkinter para gerir uma placa arduino que controla algumas funções em um carro, como ignição, faróis, estados de baterias, som etc. Toda a parte física e de instalação esta pronta.

No arduino, via conexão serial com um netbook, faco um High, e ele me retorna um caracter para confirmar o high em um rele

No python eu recebo esse caracter e modifico um texto na label.

O meu problema esta ae, consiguo ler o caracter na serial, mas a label não modifica, no código, esta aqui especificamente a situação descrita:

```
 status = StringVar()
 if iniciarconexao.receberDados == "e":
   status.set  ("Chave Ligou") 
 else:
   status.set ("Em Espera")     


 caixaestado = Label(Aplicativo, textvariable = status)
 caixaestado.pack (side="bottom")
```

Aqui estão os links para o codigos completos
[código classe Conexao Serial com arduino](https://pastebin.com/hfLaM1ag)
[Código do App](https://pastebin.com/f7TR36eU)

Toda Ajuda e Bem Vinda!

Comment: Você poderia colocar todo o seu código aqui, para poder ser analisado?

Comment: da uma olhada no meu app de dro, eu uso rasp3 e arduino nano, a rasp le a infor do nano e vai atualizando a label, https://github.com/elton1013/dro_fresadora